# Is it possible to compare the strings inside a 2D array and do calculation in the 2D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, string-comparison, calculation

is it possible to compare the strings inside a 2D array and do calculation in the 2D array? I've wrritten the code out and it doesn't shows me any error, but it stopped executing after the data in the file was stored into `fdata[][]` 2D array.

```
    #define BSIZE 1024
    char fdata[BSIZE][100]; 
    float total;
    int line = 0, ctr = 0, x = 4; 
    int remove_dataX_Fquantity(char fdata[BSIZE], int x);
    int remove_dataX_Fcode(char fdata[BSIZE], int x);

    fopen_s(&fptr, "Dist.txt", "r");
    while (!feof(fptr) && !ferror(fptr)) // read into fdata[]
    {
        if (fgets(fdata[line], 100, fptr) != NULL)
            line++;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < line; ctr++) //print out each row in fdata[] from 0 to line
    {
        printf("row %d: %s", ctr,fdata[ctr]);
    }
    do //compiler doesn't execute the code starting from here and it stopped at the code above this line.
    {
        if (strcmp(fdata[ctr], fdata[x]) == 0) //start to compare the string within the array
        {
            if (fdata[x] == NULL)
                x = 0;
            else
            {
                total = atof(fdata[ctr + 1]) + atof(fdata[x+1]); //accumulate
                *fdata[ctr + 1] = total;
                remove_dataX_Fquantity(fdata[x+1], x);
                remove_dataX_Fcode(fdata[x], x);
                printf("Code: %s, Accumulated Quantity: %.1f", fdata[ctr], total);
                ctr+4;
                x+4;
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(fdata[ctr], fdata[x]) != 0)
        {
            x+4;
        }
    } while (fdata[ctr] != NULL);
```

Here is the test data

```
fm
10.0
hospital a

sm
5.0
hospital b

fm
15.0
hospital b

sm
10.0
hospital c

om
3.0
hospital a
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: In addition to what @EricPostpischil said, hard-code the test data.   In this case it's critical to know what BSIZE is and how large your data is (both line length and number of lines).   You have function declaration in presumably a function definitions which is weird. The answer is "yes, it's possible".  strcmp returns zero for equal arguments so you probably want `!strcmp()`.  `feof()` doesn't work the way you expect so instead do `while(fgets())`.

Comment: fgets() reads line or at most 99 bytes (+ adds a '\0') so `lines++` is not technically correct.

Comment: Note that `if (fdata[x] == NULL)` will never be true, because `fdata[x]` is not a pointer. It's an array, and an array always has a non-NULL address.